# Let $M=\{(x,y,z):z=3x-y\}$. Find the orthogonal projection of a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ on $M$ and a matrix representation of $p_M$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Let $M=\{(x,y,z):z=3x-y\}$. Find the orthogonal projection of a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ on $M$ and a matrix representation of $p_M$.

I know that the orthogonal projection of two vectors is $p_vu=\frac{u \cdot v}{\|v\|^2}u$ How would I apply this to an equation.

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 3 &-1 \end{pmatrix} (\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 3 &-1 \end{pmatrix})^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 3 &-1 \end{pmatrix} (\begin{pmatrix} 10 & -3 \\ -3 & 2 \end{pmatrix})^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{11}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 3 &-1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 10 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{11}\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 10 \\ 3 & -11 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{11}\begin{pmatrix}2 & 3 & 3 \\ 3 & 10 & -11 \\ 3 & -11 & 20 \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**: find a set of basis $\{x_1,x_2\}$ for $M$ and write $X=[x_1 x_2]$ (each $x_i$ is a column vector and $X$ is $3\times 2$). Then, the matrix representation of $p_M$ is $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$. You need to verify that $p_M$, represented this way, is indeed the orthogonal projection onto $M$.

In general, if $X$ has full column rank, then $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ projects orthogonally onto the column space of $X$.

**Edit**: To find a basis, note that each vector in $M$ can be written as
$$
(x,y,3x-y)'=(x,0,3x)'+(0,y,-y)'=x(1,0,3)'+y(0,1,-1)'.
$$

Comment: Will X be $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -1 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: The formula assumes that you list the basis vectors as columns of $X$ so the dimension should be $3\times 2$.

Comment: So then $\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Check your arithmetic. Those vectors don't even belong to $M$. Maybe this post will help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733320/finding-a-basis-for-a-subspace-given-an-equation.

Comment: Sorry if this correct $\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: I have added the matrix multiplication in the question

Comment: Seems okay. Good luck!